# Concentration of Amino acid calculation?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

I found the $\mathrm{pH}$ of alanine solution, and I need its concentration, I'm given the formula below:

$$\mathrm{pH}=\frac 12 (\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}- \log c)$$

My try:

I have calculated $\mathrm{pH}$, to find $c$ I need $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$. Can someone explain that formula, what is $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$?

I know that this amino acid has $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a1}$ and $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a2}$, which do I use?

Comment: If a question is asked on Chemistry SE site, the site policy expects authors to elaborate the question, e.g. by searching in textbook+online resources, writing what has been found, understood or tried and what is the stumble stone. The quick questions without explicitly expressed solving effort are not very welcome, and may be voted to be closed. OTOH, explicitly written effort to answer the question raises the probability to get a satisfying answer.

Comment: Search for the term *acid dissociation constant* .

Comment: @Poutnik I dont understand, I know the term pKa... I just wonder which one to use? of the acid correct? since there are 2 pkas for each amino acid

Comment: OK, but your question is unclear in that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clarify:

$\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a1}: \ce{NH3^{+}-R-COOH <=> NH3^{+}-R-COO- + H+}$

$\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a2}: \ce{NH3^{+}-R-COO- <=> NH2-R-COO- + H+}$

For aminoacids, the the pH calculation is the same as for acidic salts of diprotic weak acids $\ce{MHA}$.

Unfortunately for you, $\mathrm{pH}=\dfrac{\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a1}+\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a2}}{2}$ as the very good approximation, so it is almost independent on the concentration, so you cannot determine the concentration from $\mathrm{pH}$.

More exactly. you could, but by a much more complex formula as you listed above, as it would be very inacurate because of high $\dfrac{\mathrm{d}c}{\mathrm{d(pH)}}$

By other words, aminoacid solutions act as low capacity pH buffers ( because of quite a big difference of their $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a1}$ and $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a2}$.